Understanding the canonical factorization $\mathrm{Ker}(u)\to \mathrm{Coker}(u)$ in the category of filtered modules
Let $F_A$ denote the category of filtered modules over a commutative unital filtered ring $A$ with morphisms being $A$-linear maps $u\colon M\to N$ such that $u(M_n)\subset N_n$. The book states that we have a canonical factorization:
$\mathrm{Ker}(u)\to M\to \mathrm{Coim}(u)\xrightarrow{\theta}\mathrm{Im}(u)\to N\to \mathrm{Coker}(u)$
where $\theta$ is a bijection.
But why is this $\theta$ only a bijection when it is the unique isomorphism induced by the universal properties of cokernel and kernel?
EDIT:
The exact quote (Serre's Local Algebra pg. 11-12) is

In $F_A$, the notions of injective (resp. surjective) morphisms are
the usual notions. Every morphism $u\colon M\to N$ admits a kernel
$\mathrm{Ker}(u)$ and a cokernel $\mathrm{Coker}(u)$: the underlying
modules of $\mathrm{Ker}(u)$ and $\mathrm{Coker}(u)$ are the usual
kernel and cokernel, together with the induced filtration and the
quotient filtration. We similarly define
$\mathrm{Im}(u)=\mathrm(Ker)(N\to \mathrm{Coker}(u))$ and
$\mathrm{Coim}(u)=\mathrm{Coker}(\mathrm{Ker}(u)\to M)$. We have the
canonical factorization:
$\mathrm{Ker}(u)\to M\to\mathrm{Coim}(u)\xrightarrow{\theta}\mathrm{Im}(u)\to N\to\mathrm{Coker}(u)$
where $\theta$ is bijective. One says that $u$ is a strict morphism if
$\theta$ is an isomorphism of filtered modules; it amounts to the same
as saying that $u(M_n)=N_n\cap u(M)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. There
exist bijective morphisms that are not isomorphisms ($F_A$ is not an
abelian category).


It's not clear at which level you're confused here. Do you know the definition of the objects and maps in this diagram? $\text{coim} = \text{coker}(\text{ker}(u))$ and $\text{im} = \text{ker}(\text{coker}(u))$. Can you compute these? Can you argue that their universal properties imply that there must be a map between them?

Also various composites of maps in this diagram are zero, the intended meaning isn't that we're factoring a map from the kernel to the cokernel. This is just a canonical sequence of maps you can write down in any additive category with kernels and cokernels. Are you familiar with the corresponding sequence in an abelian category, where the middle map is always an isomorphism? (This is why you've never heard of the coimage before.)

@QiaochuYuan I know about the universal properties kernel, cokernel and how image, coimage are defined from those. I see that the composition of the first two and the last two morphisms are zero by these. If the coimage was given as the usual $\cong M/\mathrm{Ker}(u)$ then I could see how $\theta$ would be an isomorphism of modules but perhaps not a homeomorphism. I tried to prove that $\theta$ is a homeomorphism iff $u(M_n)=N_n\cap u(M)$ but failed. I am not familiar with the corresponding sequence in an abelian category or what makes the category of filtered modules additive but not abelian.

Did the author really say it is only a bijection? I'm not quite sure what your question is, but surely the only possible problem could be that bijective maps in this category aren't isomorphisms. You seem to understand everything else here?

@FShrike Yes it is only said to be a bijection and not in general an isomorphism of filtered modules (although it is an isomorphism of modules). The point was that $\theta$ does not necessarily respect the filtered module structure. The part I cannot make sense of is why the universal properties are not enough to guarantee the filtered module isomorphism. As a note, the above statement about homeomorphism equivalence in the comments is not true. Not all homeomorphisms are filtered module isomorphisms.

If the coinage and image are being taken in the category of filtered modules then $\theta$ automatically is a map of filtered modules

@FShrike Well they are the cokernel and kernel of kernel and cokernel respectively, both of which are taken to be filtered modules. This should imply that the coimage and image are also objects in the category by their definition and we should get the result because we end up with a commutative diagram where image is also the cokernel of kernel but the book states that we don't. If it were the case that coimage and cokernel were not filtered then I would completely understand this result and even have a counterexample. I'm posting the exact quote from the book in an edit to the post.

@FShrike The way I understand the statement is that there is always a bijective morphism from coimage to the image yet the inverse of this morphism need to be a morphism which is why we don't have an isomorphism but the thing I am curious about is that if such objects satisfy the universal property of kernel and cokernel then isn't the morphism between them an iso by the universal property?

@ephe Well, not all categories are Abelian! It is not guaranteed that $\mathrm{Coim}\cong\mathrm{Im}$. The two objects share a priori different universal properties!

@FShrike Would you mind expanding on what you mean when you say that these objects share different universal properties?

@ephe Well, Coimage and Image are just defined differently. If they happen to coincide in this way (as they do in Abelian categories) then this is a theorem and something to be "surprised" by. So we should not expect it to be purely formal and automatic that $\theta$ is an isomorphism. That said, $\theta$ should be a map of filtered modules assuming we work with kernels and cokernels of filtered modules... but I have never looked at the category of filtered modules per se so I could be overlooking a subtlety

@FShrike Got it. So the kernel and cokernel aren't defined by a universal property in the category of filtered modules but rather one in the category of modules and then we add a filtered modules structures on them. So the isomorphism we attain via the universal property is only that of modules. The filtrations induced on the coimage and image do not necessarily have the coincide.

@ephe Ah, that would be the issue then! We're switching categories, and the functors involved don't preserve/reflect all the limits and colimits and isomorphisms

To summarize:

The kernel and cokernel are defined in the category of filtered $A$-modules and satisfy the usual universal properties in this category.

The morphism $\theta\colon\mathrm{coim}(u)\rightarrow\mathrm{im}(u)$ is a homomorphism of filtered $A$-modules, induced by the universal properties of coimage and image in the category of filtered $A$-modules.

There is no reason for $\theta$ to be an isomorphism just because it is uniquely induced by a universal property.

The forgetful functor from the category of filtered $A$-modules to the category of plain $A$-modules preserves (co-)limits, so the usual isomorphism theorem implies that $\theta$ induces an isomorphism of the underlying $A$-modules (equivalently, a bijection on the underlying sets).

There are homomorphisms of filtered $A$-modules that are isomorphisms on the underlying $A$-modules yet not isomorphisms of filtered $A$-modules. Take $M$ to be your favorite $A$-module, let $M^{\prime}$ and $M^{\prime\prime}$ be $M$ equipped with the filtrations $M^{\prime}_n=0$ and $M^{\prime\prime}_n=M$ for all $n$ respectively. The set-theoretic identity is a homomorphism of filtered $A$-modules $f\colon M^{\prime}\rightarrow M^{\prime\prime}$ that is a bijection yet not an isomorphism (why? consider the possible homomorphisms of filtered $A$-modules $M^{\prime\prime}\rightarrow M^{\prime}$). In fact, in this case $\theta=f$.



Given your initial bullet point, the part that I don't understand is this: the universal property of cokernel says that any construction satisfying the conditions is unique up to unique isomorphism. $\mathrm{coim}(u)$ is the cokernel of kernel but $\mathrm{im}(u)$ also satisfies the properties of being a cokernel for the kernel. Then  how do we not have a unique isomorphism between them?

@ephe It is simply not true that $\mathrm{im}(u)$ is a cokernel of the kernel. Try verifying the universal property in the counter-example I gave; you will see it is not fulfilled.

Oh. I see now that the diagram I have made was not actually giving me that. But then how do we attain the map from comaige to the image via universal properties? What other universal do we have than the ones for kernel and cokernel?

@ephe You use precisely those. The map $M\rightarrow\mathrm{im}(u)$ vanishes on $\ker(u)$, so it factors through its cokernel, which is $\mathrm{coim}(u)$.
